# 302 Redirect has no domain

Tags: qt, http, networking, redirect

I'm trying to figure out what the best way of dealing with a URL that redirects to a path (without a domain included).

I see that this URL (using the wheregoes http redirection tracer)

```
http://razbor-poletov.com/images/logo_final_b_300.jpg
```

gets redirected to:

```
/images/logo_final_b_300.jpg
```

I'm used to seeing a domain included in the redirection message that I feed into my  QNetworkRequest. Is this a compliant redirection? How do the browsers deal with this since the redirection seems to work in firefox, chrome, etc..)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a compliant redirection. Simply always resolve the field value against the URI you sent the request to.